# Which question guidelines exist on security stackexchange?

Tags: support, acceptable-question, question-quality

It seems that one should [avoid question about cyber security tools](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/should-the-security-stack-exchange-tour-page-list-best-security-tool-questions-a) (Since it is very opinion based. But is it allowed to ask about how specific popular tools work?), no code reviews, [obviously no blackhat answers/questions](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/897/clarify-our-stance-on-black-hat-questions/898#898) and I think much more things which one should consider by asking a question. Is there any *FAQ* or some unwritten guidelines which I should follow? I totally agree about those guidelines but would like to know more.

---

https://security.stackexchange.com/tour and https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask don't really answer my questions.

Comment: "Review audits" aren't about reviewing code, but about user self-moderation on the site.

Answer (score 4):

You only got one down vote on your sqlmap question, and two upvotes, so I would not use that as an example of "downvotes"

There is a lot of guidance written - it's actually pretty extensive. We haven't collated it into a FAQ, but reading the posts here on meta should give you a very good idea of our stance on most kinds of questions.

So I'd suggest initially reading those posts in the Related sidebar to the right, and then just continuing to browse meta, maybe focusing on the [acceptable-question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptable-question) tag initially.

Comment: "read everything. profit.", is not very helpful, I hope you know. A *FAQ* would be really great.

Comment: It may happen - they take time, and it would require some community volunteers to do that in between their real jobs. Most SE sites don't have a specific faq other than the main and meta.se ones, as the principles are the same for all, and the [about] pages have a whole lot of info

Comment: Go up there to the little question mark at the top and read all of that.